# Anything additional to do about an inappropriate edit that was accepted?

Tags: discussion

Forgive me if this answer is obvious but I didn't find anything in the guidelines that seemed pertinent.  I recently came across a proposed edit that added what I believe to be completely inappropriate text to a question.  In particular, the editor added the following to the top:

> Please excuse my poor grammar :(

Aside from this the only edit was the addition of two articles to two sentences.

I chose to "Reject & Edit" and made a whole bunch of improvements to the grammar, but while editing was informed that it had been edited.  After completing and saving, I checked the question and found that in the edit history, the edit that I had rejected had actually been accepted by someone.

Finally, this brings me to my question:  **Is there any way to refer that back to the person who approved the useless edit so that they can learn from it?**  Clearly this can get into a situation of fine lines, but the above seems to be a pretty clear case.

Comment: The edit was approved by the question's owner, not much you can do about that. A polite note to the editor would be a good idea though. (Editors are `@ping` able.)

Comment: @Mat Wow, how did I miss that?  Thanks.  I was trying to puzzle out how a rep 1 person got to approve an edit.  Still, I wonder if the larger question is worth answering?  Is there a mechanism for giving feedback to an approver on an edit?

Comment: Generally, no. Though in some cases, I pinged someone on one of their posts to make them *very* politely aware of guidelines regarding reviewing, linking to some reviews they did, giving a detailled breakdown what should have been done instead, and giving links to some of the relevant help-pages and meta-posts. Anyway, if it's blatant enough, raise an "other" flag starting with a handful words concisely describing the problem, and all the relevant details (links).

Comment: Why would the _editor_ add a note apologizing for poor grammar? Are they apologizing for adding bad grammar in their edits or are they saying the OP ought to have apologized for their own bad grammar? The latter would be grossly inappropriate and rude but either way it's useless noise.

Comment: @BSMP in the specific case I misread the names and didn't realize that the editor *was* the OP.  That part is answered.  The remainder of the question stands, though:  Is there a mechanism to send an edit that is inappropriate back to the editor?  I realize that there is the edit review system but I do not believe that all edits are reviewed, are they?

Comment: @BSMP Sorry, my mind wasn't tracking.  I didn't state that accurately.  The remaining question is not about the original editor at all... It's about someone *accepting* something as an edit that they really shouldn't have.  I'm wondering if there's an official feedback cycle for that.  Sorry!